# Многострочный ввод в Java. Нужно сразу принять все строки, которые поступают на input, чтобы с ними работать дальше, а не частями

Tags: java, input

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class OrderRestaurant {
 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      TreeMap<String, LinkedList<Integer>> orderMap = new TreeMap<String, LinkedList<Integer>>();
      Set<Integer> tableSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
      
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line = null;
    
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] orders = line.split(",");
    
        for (int i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
            
            tableSet.add(Integer.parseInt(orders[1]));  
        }
            
            if (!(orderMap.containsKey(orders[2]))) {
                LinkedList<Integer> numbersTables = new LinkedList<>();
                numbersTables.add(Integer.parseInt(orders[1]));
            
                orderMap.put(orders[2], numbersTables);
            } else {
                orderMap.get(orders[2]).addLast(Integer.parseInt(orders[1]));
            }
         
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder("Table");
        
        Set<String>keysOrderMapSet=orderMap.keySet();
        for (String keyString : keysOrderMapSet) {
            sBuilder.append(',').append(keyString);
        }
        
         for(Integer key : tableSet){
             sBuilder.append("\n").append(key);
            
             for(Map.Entry<String, LinkedList<Integer>> entry : orderMap.entrySet())
             {
                 LinkedList<Integer> numbersOrder = entry.getValue();
                 int counterOrder = 0;
                 
                 for (int i = 0; i < numbersOrder.size(); i++) {
                     if(numbersOrder.get(i)==key) {
                         counterOrder++;
                     }
                   }
                 sBuilder.append(',').append(counterOrder);
                 }
         }
         System.out.println(sBuilder.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: точнее описывайте задачу. по вашей формулировке непонятно, что именно вы хотите сделать. если вам нужно прочитать файл построчно, либо вы ожидаете ввод пользователя с консоли, то сначала складывайте все данные в коллекцию, а уже поптом их обрабатывайте

Comment: Да, именно. Мне поступает ввод с консоли в формате нескольких строк  и мне нужна коллекция - я не понимаю как мне понять, что ввод закончен и можно с этой коллекцией работать

Comment: много вариантов. например, пользователь вводит текст построчно, нажимая  enter  после каждой строки. а вы это пишите в коллецию (в бесконечном цикле). после окончания ввода пользователь , не вводя никакого тексте, нажимает enter. а вы перед тем , как писать в коллекцию, проверяете , не пустая ли это строка. если пустая , то прерываете цикл (ввод закончен)и начинаете работать с коллекцией

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть 2 варианта: в начале указываете сколько будет элементов и останавливаетесь, когда нужное число элементов считано, либо создаете специальный символ/слово, который ставится в конце данных, аки точка в предложения

Comment: тест предусматривает, что в поле ввода неограниченное количество строк может быть и указать сколько будет элементов не подойдет. если я добавлю символ, то просто к Enter добавится символ и я ничего не выигрываю

Comment: @AdministratorAdministrator не понимаю о чем вы. Если вы перед тем как начинаете вводить данные уже знаете сколько их всего, то вы легко можете указать число строк, сущностей, чего-нибудь, что поможет понять что больше данных не будет. Не можете - окей, считываем построчно до тех пор, пока не считаем слово end. Соответственно пользователь в консоль вгоняет сколько надо данных и в конце ставит слово end